# Can a Hamkins infinite time Turing Machine with infinite Super Turing jumps (from higher type oracles) get the power to decide $\Sigma_1^2$ sets?

Tags: set-theory, computational-number-theory, computability-theory, lo.logic

Hamkins showed that his infinite time Turing machine has the power to decide some $\Delta_2^1$ sets. I wonder if some modifications of the machine could be made to reach level $\Sigma_1^2$ sets, or, if no modifications on sight, if the power of his machine plus infinitely iterated super jumps from super oracles (those consisting of uncountable sets of real numbers) could reach that level.

Comment: no, I mean of real numbers, because the input of his machines is a real number, that is, an infinite sequence of 1's and 0's (the tape has infinite length). this is an extract from his article: Thus,we want somehow to allow a set of real numbers,such as the halting problem H,to become an oracle for the machines.And since such a set could be uncountable,and these  in particular is definitely uncountable,we can’t expect to be able to write out the entire contents of the oracle on an extra tape,as in the classical theory."

Comment: I think this is a bit too vague - how do you propose for a Turing machine to make use of a set of reals as an oracle? If you want to use higher type objects as oracles, and reach set-theoretically huge classes like $\Sigma^2_1$, I think your best bet is to look not at infinite time Turing machines, but at $E$-recursion, which can handle arbitrary sets as oracles.

Comment: A good source on $E$-recursion is www.math.harvard.edu/~sacks/erecint.pdf. By the way, what $\Delta^1_2$ sets can Hamkins' infinite time Turing machines decide? I'm not very familiar with that setup.

Comment: Noah, one uses an arbitrary set $A$ of reals as an oracle to an infinite time Turing machine by allowing the machine to make membership queries of $A$. Thus, there is a (blank) oracle tape, which the machine can write some real $x$ on, and then receive an answer whether $x\in A$ or not. So it can get information about $A$, but only for reals $x$ that it can produce. This is analogous to constructibility-relative-to-a-predicate, as in $L[A]$ or $L[\mu]$, as opposed to relative constructibility, as in $L(A)$ or $L(\mathbb{R})$.  

Comment: Julian, can you confirm that you want $\Sigma^2_1$, which is a very significant step up in complexity, as opposed to $\Sigma^1_2$, which is a comparatively smaller step up from $\Delta^1_2$?

Comment: Noah, the infinite time Turing machines can decide whether a given real codes a well-order---this is the "count-through" argument in my original paper with Andy Lewis. Since this is a complete $\Pi^1_1$ set, it follows that every $\Pi^1_1$ set is infinite time decidable. Since the decidable sets are closed under Boolean combinations, this pushes properly into $\Delta^1_2$.

Comment: Joel, yes, actually, the reason I chose a $\Sigma_1^2$ is that I was interested to know if it could decide the CH (which I understand you do not think has a specific answer, based on your multiverse theory)

Comment: @Joel, thanks! I could tell that infinite time Turing machines could decide WO; is there a good description of the subclass of the $\Delta^1_2$ sets that infinite time Turing machines compute?

Comment: One the funkiest question titles of all time!

Comment: Noah, it strictly exceeds the closure of $\Pi^1_1$ under Boolean combinations. If you use the boldface version, with arbitrary real parameters, then it is a $\sigma$-algebra closed under Suslin's operation $\cal A$ and properly containing the C-sets of Selivanovski. But it doesn't seem to have a nice independent characterization. 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One should think of the class $\Delta^1_2$ as truly enormous, closed under powerful set-theoretical constructions. It 
may help to keep in mind that the minimal transitive model of ZFC, if it exists, is contained inside $\Delta^1_2$, and so
one cannot jump out of $\Delta^1_2$ with a computational operation that is absolute to transitive models of 
set theory. Andy Lewis and I pointed out in our paper [Infinite time Turing machines](http://jdh.hamkins.org/ittms/)
that $\Delta^1_2$ is closed under the boldface jump: if $A$ is $\Delta^1_2$, then so is $A^\blacktriangledown$.

In particular, let us imagine that we equip an infinite time Turing machine with a jump-operator black box, 
which whenever a real $x$ is written on a 
special tape, then the jump $x^\triangledown$ appears on another special tape. Such a machine could iteratively compute the jump 
transfinitely often, as suggested in your question. Nevertheless, these machines are 
still stuck inside $\Delta^1_2$; every function they compute and every set they decide will have complexity at most 
$\Delta^1_2$. (In 
fact, this model is simply equivalent to having the set $0^\blacktriangledown$ as a set oracle. And we can iterate this process an 
enormous number of times, so that oracle $0^{\blacktriangledown^{(\alpha)}}$ will still be in $\Delta^1_2$.)

Meanwhile, aiming to get beyond the $\Delta^1_2$ barrier, Philip Welch observed that the connection 
between infinite time Turing machines and $\Delta^1_2$ is related to the 
fact that the limit stage operation of the machine is defined by the limsup, a definition of complexity 
$\Sigma_2$ (the value is 
$0$ at the limit if there is an earlier stage, such that for all later stages, the value is $0$). With the goal of finding 
a corresponding machine-computation
model giving rise to $\Delta^1_3$ and higher levels of the projective hierarchy, Philip Welch and Sy Friedman introduced 
new machine models with more complicated limit behavior in their article 
"Hypermachines", Journal of Symbolic Logic, 76, No.2, June 2011, 620-636. As far as achieving $\Sigma^1_n$ might be concerned, this 
seems to be the most promising answer to your question.

As for $\Sigma^2_1$, I don't know of anything resembling infinite time Turing machines that approaches it. At this level of 
complexity (and even at levels of complexity within the projective hierarchy), the behavior of a computational device 
able to decide such properties would have to be sensitive to the background
set theory in which the device is operated, whereas our more ordinary conceptions of "computation" tend to be that 
they are absolute, for example, 
to forcing extensions.

Comment: Joel, super clear answer, case closed. Thanks!!!

Comment: Julian, thanks for your vote of confidence!  But I think we should leave it open whether a clever person might come up with a concrete computational model approaching $\Sigma^2_1$. 

Comment: @Joel Is the fact that $\Delta_2^1$ is closed under the boldface jump $A^\blacktriangledown$
due to the fact that you limited the oracles to questions about writable (or constructible) reals (which is limited by the complexity of the limit stage rules), instead of allowing an extra tape with uncountable number of cells (which as you mention, clearly we cannot
expect always to be able to write such an object out on a tape, but suppose you could).  So your oracles are not as strong (arbitrary sets of reals) as they could potentially be?
      


Comment: Yes, the ITTM model has only ordinary tapes with $\omega$ many cells. I believe our oracle concept for sets of reals is the right one to consider, but I suppose I can imagine stronger ones. If you want to use uncountably many cells, then if the cells are to be well-ordered (in order to mak sense of traversing them), then you will not just be  putting the set on the oracle tape, but the set in some order, which would carry more information.

Comment: Meanwhile, one can think of our oracle concept as having the yes-no answers for every real written out somewhere, with a call-by-address scheme, so to get to the information about a particular real, you just write it into the register, and then receive the yes/no answer. This way of thinking about it seems closer to what you describe, but is functionally equivalent to our oracle operation.

Comment: Thanks! just one more question (or should I post it a a separate question?) Is there any reason you extended the classical concept into transfinite ordinal time but not into transfinite ordinal space?

Comment: The ordinal-tape machines have by now been introduced and studied by Peter Koepke and others in his group, and there are infinite time register machines, and ordinal register machines, etc., exploring the full range of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read about their work. But I was just curious about your personal opinion, which I highly valuate, of why you restricted yourself in the initial proposal to the time generalization but to the space one. Did you considered it but didn't like it, or you just didn't considered it at all?

Comment: Well, thanks for the vote of confidence. In the beginning, we were interested in using the same hardware as an ordinary Turing machine, and an ordinary Turing machine has only an $\omega$ length tape. But Jeff Kidder and I did also consider machines with transfinite tape; but the operation of them seemed fussy to control, since to re-access later parts of the tape, you seem to have to keep sending the head all the way back to the start and then out again. We didn't happen to hit upon Koepke's elegant operational rules, which solve this issue.

Comment: Please let me know if you don't want me to keep posting questions to you here. My understanding was that the machine reaches stage $\omega_1$ in finite time, but according to an answer to a question that I posted at math.se (  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341895/the-real-line-has-cardinality-at-most-aleph-2-but-transfinite-ordinal-space
peo)  it should take infinite time to reach stage $\omega_1$. Did I misunderstood you article? 

Comment: In terms of understanding infinitary algorithms, the relevant measure of the length of a computation is the number of computational steps, rather than the number of seconds. That is, we measure time in terms of the number of steps of computation. From this perspective, any infinitary computation takes infinite time. Meanwhile, some people are reassured that every countable ordinal can be embedded into the real line, and so one can imagine that the infinitely many steps of computation take altogether a finite amount of time. 

Comment: But it is not possible to embed $\omega_1$ or any uncountable ordinal into the real line, since every cut in the reals has countable cofinality. So one cannot undertake an uncountable process in a real-number of seconds, if every step is to take some nonzero real-number amount of time. So one cannot view the length $\omega_1$ supertasks as taking "finite time" in that sense. 